# Getting a valid JNI environment pointer

Tags: java-native-interface

I am working on a very large and complex C++ application that is using JNI in several unrelated places for different tasks. The platform is RHEL 6. Because I don't know if a JNI was already created by the application, I am using this method to find a JVM and attach to it:

```
JOI_RetCode JavaObjectInterface::initJVM()
{
  if (jvm_ == NULL)
  {
    // Is there an existing JVM already created?
    jsize jvm_count = 0;
    jint result = JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs (&jvm_, 1, &jvm_count);
    if (result != JNI_OK)
      return JOI_ERROR_CHECK_JVM;      

    if (jvm_count == 1)
    {
      // Yes - use it.
      result = jvm_->GetEnv((void**) &jenv_, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
      switch (result)
      {
        case JNI_OK:
          logger::log(CAT_JNI, LL_DEBUG, "Attached to an existing JVM.");
          jenv_ = env;
          break;

        case JNI_EDETACHED:
          result = jvm_->AttachCurrentThread((void**) &jenv_, NULL);   
          if (result != JNI_OK)
            return JOI_ERROR_ATTACH_JVM;

          needToDetach_ = true;
          logger::log(CAT_JNI, LL_DEBUG, "Attached to an existing JVM from another thread.");
          break;

        case JNI_EVERSION:
          logger::log(CAT_JNI, LL_DEBUG, "Attaching to a JVM of the wrong version.");
          return JOI_ERROR_JVM_VERSION;
          break;

        default:
          logger::log(CAT_JNI, LL_DEBUG, "Unknown error Attaching to an existing JVM.");
          return JOI_ERROR_ATTACH_JVM;
          break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // No - create a new one.
      result = createJVM();
      if (result != JNI_OK)
        return JOI_ERROR_CREATE_JVM;

      needToDetach_ = false;
      logger::log(CAT_JNI, LL_DEBUG, "Created a new JVM.");
    }
  }

  return JOI_OK;
}
```

The JVM pointers are defined as class data members as follows:

```
JavaVM*   jvm_;
JNIEnv*   jenv_;
```

Now, when a JVM was created elsewhere before I call thid method, the result is that the call to JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs() returns a JVM pointer, and the call to GetEnv() returns JNI_OK, and updates jenv_ with a pointer that looks valid. So far so good. However, when I next do:

```
  jclass javaClass = jenv_->FindClass(className);
```

I get an exception thrown. I cannot get any data from the exception itself because stderr is redirected to /dev/null, so if I call ExceptionDescribe() the output goes to hell. Interrogating the exception object requires a working JNI to call FindClass("Throwable"), so that's not working either.

The call to FindClass() is good because when I am creating the first JVM, it worksd fine.

Can anyone help me find the stupid mistake that I must have done here somewhere?
Thanks,
Yuval.

Comment: The `JNIEnv` pointer is usually thread-specific.  It's easiest to simply look it up on demand using the JVM reference, rather than saving a thread-specific version of it for each thread you might be operating on.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you elaborate a bit please on how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The `JNIEnv` pointer is usually thread-specific.  It's easiest to simply look it up on demand using the JVM reference.

For whatever block of code that needs to access `JNIEnv`, look it up in scope for that local block:

```
JNIEnv* jenv_;
int result = jvm_->GetEnv((void**) &jenv_, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
if (result == JNI_EDETACHED) {
    // attach
}
// Do what you gotta do here
// ...
if (needs_detach) {
    // detach
}
```

That way you'll be sure to get a valid `JNIEnv` no matter your context.

The main takeaway from this is "don't cache `JNIEnv`".

Comment: Well, isn't that what my code is doing? Besides, in my case, the call top GetENv returns JNI_OK, which means its the same thread, and sets the env pointer right there. The pointer returned seems OK, but when I use it to call FindClass(), I get an exception.

Comment: Your code appears to be assigning the env var to a class member, which implies that you're hanging onto it for use in some context other than the immediately local block.  The most common error with `FindClass` is using an incorrect class signature; what is the value of the string you are using?